# Postgres: create a new jsonb object with matched values

Tags: postgresql

So I have this table `questions` that have a `settings` jsonb column:

```
{
    id: 'question-id-1',
    settings: {
      foo1: true,
      foo2: true,
      bar: false
    }
},
{
    id: 'question-id-2',
    settings: {
      bar: true
    }
}
```

now I want to make a postgres db update migration script that results to:

```
{
    id: 'question-id-1',
    settings: {
      foo1: true,
      foo2: true,
      bar: false,
      opts: ['foo1', 'foo2']
    }
},
{
    id: 'question-id-2',
    settings: {
      bar: true,
      opts: ['bar']
    }
}
```

so only those that has values `true` is added to a new `opts` array inside `settings`.

This is for Postgres 9.5.

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a function to update the column:

```
create or replace function add_opts(jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select $1 || jsonb_build_object('opts', jsonb_agg(key))
    from jsonb_each_text($1)
    where value::bool;
$$;
```

Test:

```
with questions(settings) as (
values
('{
  "foo1": true,
  "foo2": true,
  "bar": false
}'::jsonb)
)

select add_opts(settings)
from questions;

                               add_opts                               
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"bar": false, "foo1": true, "foo2": true, "opts": ["foo1", "foo2"]}
(1 row)
```

Your update query should look like this:

```
update questions
set settings = add_opts(settings);
```

---

The variant which eliminates the `opts` array when there are no set options:

```
create or replace function add_opts(jsonb)
returns jsonb language sql as $$
    select case
        when jsonb_agg(key) is null then $1
        else $1 || jsonb_build_object('opts', jsonb_agg(key))
    end
    from jsonb_each_text($1)
    where value::bool;
$$;
```

Comment: Awesome. This works! Just an extra question: this creates an object `opts: null` in case of no true values found. Do you think there is a away around it (not having the `opts` at all)?

Comment: sorry to bother you. I have been researching but couldn't find the solution -- would be really appreciate any help from you again.

Is there away to get the value of the opts as ARRAY, not jsonb?

I tried array_agg but it still returns jsonb.

Comment: No problem with your additional questions. See this [SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/89b90/1)